How to use onMounted after await statements?
I need to define an onMounted hook after the first await statement because the hook depends on the awaited value. But this results in a warning:
onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.

I can't move onMounted above the await statement. One method is to await the value inside the hook itself, but I need this value in other places before the component is mounted (so having duplicate awaits doesn't seem like a good solution). What is the best way to solve this?

In Vue 3's Composition API, the onMounted hook and other lifecycle hooks must be called synchronously within the setup function, before any await statements. This requirement ensures that the hooks are registered before any asynchronous operations that might cause the component instance to become inactive.
However, you can work around this limitation by defining the onMounted hook synchronously and then performing the asynchronous operation within the hook itself. Additionally, you can use a ref to store the awaited value so that it can be accessed both before and after the component is mounted.
Here's an example of how to achieve this:


import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const awaitedValue = ref(null);

    // Perform the asynchronous operation and store the result in awaitedValue
    const initialize = async () => {
      awaitedValue.value = await someAsyncFunction();
    };

    // Register the onMounted hook
    onMounted(async () => {
      await initialize();
      // Perform other actions that depend on awaitedValue after the component is mounted
      console.log('Component mounted and awaitedValue:', awaitedValue.value);
    });

    // Call the async function immediately to get the value before the component is mounted
    initialize();

    return {
      awaitedValue,
    };
  },
};



